# Как изменить цветовую схему у surface pygame

Tags: python, pygame, color

требуется изменить цветовую схему поверхности в pygame, например сначала у меня есть синие изображение/surface и со временем он будет становится красного оттенка(это уже неважно, главное как изменять оттенок), заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Что вы попробовали уже сделать сами? Добавьте, пожалуйста, попытки в ваш вопрос.

Comment: @СергейКох не знаю как отредактировать вопрос но скажу здесь, я пробовал и изображения ставить альфа цвет примерно на 150, и на нижнем слое рисовать квадрат нужного цвета, немного получился подобный эффект, но не красивый, когда альфа у изображения маленькая то его почти не видно и оно тусклое, а когда альфа большая то цвет почти не изменяется, думаю есть какая то функция у surface для изменения оттенков но не нашел в документации

Comment: Какие проблемы? Изменяйте в цикле одну (две или сразу три) составляющую цвета (0, 0, 0) до (255, 255, 255).

Comment: Или составьте сами список цветов для перехода и пройдитесь по нему. https://mike632t.wordpress.com/2018/02/10/displaying-a-list-of-the-named-colours-available-in-pygame/

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашему объяснению в комментарии эта функция делает то, что вам нужно:

```py
import pygame


def replace_color(s: pygame.Surface, color1: tuple[int, int, int], color2: tuple[int, int, int]):
    """Закрашивает все пикселы поверхности s цвета color1 цветом color2."""
    for x in range(0, s.get_width()):
        for y in range(0, s.get_height()):
            if s.get_at((x, y)) == pygame.Color(*color1):
                s.set_at((x, y), pygame.Color(*color2))
```

Comment: Не совсем то что я хотел, мне нужно изменять цвет поверхности а не заливать её каким то цветом, например на поверхности есть фото неба, и сделать так чтобы небо стало красным а солнце каким нибудь зелёным

Comment: @AndroCoder, изменил ответ по вашему описанию, посмотрите теперь.

Comment: Ладно, мне нужно изменять это в реал тайме с высоким фпс, попробую написать dll на С чтобы там это быстро делать